# Greasemonkey(FireFoxaddon)でclick処理について

Tags: javascript, firefox

https://addons.mozilla.org/ja/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Greasemonkey(FireFoxaddon)でclick処理をするスクリプトを設置して
実行
してみたのですが、クリックはできてはいるようなので
すが、
思うような結果が得られないので困っております。

クリックは発動できているようなのですが、
何度も同じ処理がリピートされてしまい、クリックして停止ができません。

あるサイトで、ボタンをクリックしてポップアップを開き、
ポップアップ画面の中で操作を行い、またボタンをクリックするといった処理の
スクリプトを作ったのですが、高速で処理が終了してしまいます。

しかしながら、このスクリプトは、ChromeのAutoscriptRunner では
同様のスクリプトが問題なく動いております。

Greasemonkeyではclickの書き方が何かちがうのでしょうか？
また、click のあとに処理を止めるように記載が必要なのでしょうか・・

実行したプログラム
document.getElementsByClassName("openMultiExhibit")[0].click();

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14177965009

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/88057